# Media queries go into effect on strange values

Tags: css, reactjs, responsive-design, media-queries

this is my media query as i try to make my react app responsive.

```
@media screen and (max-height: 800px) {
    font-size: 65px;
    .shuttleObject{
      width: 90%;
    }
  }
}
```

The thing is, when i try to change the height and width in the web developer console in chrome, this code works when:

width: 976px
height: 796px

then when i go

width: 976px
height: 797px

it doesnt go into effect

When i change the width to 977px its in effect again. Why does it work like that and is there something that i can do to only work how its supposed to, meaning that <800px = in effect, > 800 = not.

If I should provide more, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

You can just set the required css properties as intial value, then change it to accordingly, when screen size height is greater than 800px height. (As Given Example).

```css
//use this as intial css values.
.demo{
    font-size: 65px;
    .shuttleObject{
      width: 90%;
    }
 }
 
//Apply css as per your requirement if height is greater than 800px

 @media screen and (min-height:800px) {
    /* style changes when the screen gets larger */
}
```

Comment: Very informative. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I forgot to add this line of code in the head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

After this added line it works correctly.